# Typescript error after updating from version 2.9.2 to 3.7.5

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

**I have an angular (version 6) project that is using typescript version 2.9.2.**

I'm migrating to the latest version of angular, version 9.

**One step of the migration is to update the typescript version, to 3.7.5.**

After updating typescript I get a compilation error on one of the libs - https://github.com/jf3096/json-typescript-mapper - This lib is not active anymore.

> 187             instance[key] =  decoratorMetaData.customConverter.fromJson(json[decoratorMetaData.name || key]);
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   node_modules/json-typescript-mapper/index.ts:189:13 - error TS2536: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

Anyone had a similar problem after updating typescript?
Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Angular 6 does not support Typescript v3.7.5 officially. Some extra configurations are to be done, to make it work properly (if by any chance possible)

Comment: @boop_the_snoot This error occurs after I already migrate to version 9 of angular.

Comment: Did you follow the migration steps properly? [Please take a look again on the upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:9.0l2)

Comment: I did. This is more related to typescript than angular.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned in the comments that you've followed everything as per guide, you may try the steps given below by manually upgrading TypeScript version.

Modify `tsconfig.json` file add:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    // some props
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true // <- ADD
  }
}
```

(Optional) Delete `package-lock.json` and [`node-modules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npkill) folder.

- Do `npm i` again
- Add `npm i -D typescript@3.7.5` if not already done.

In `src/polyfills.ts`, at the very end add:

```
// @ts-ignore
window.__importDefault = function (mod) {
    return mod && mod.__esModule ? mod : { default: mod };
};
```

Now continue testing your application by creating a build